# Is this a correct proof that a sequence of random variables converges in probability.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let
$ {X_{n}} $ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $ X_{i} \sim U(-1,1)$

Form $Y_{n} = \text{max}_{k=1 \ldots n} X_{k}$ Prove that $Y_{n} $ converges in probability to a constant c and determine that constant.

Is the following a valid proof of this fact?

As c is a constant convergence in distribution implies convergence in probability. Thus.

$F_{Y_{n}} = F^{n}_{X_{n}} = 1^{n} -> 1 \text{ as } n->\infty$

$X_{n} \text{ converges in distribution to 1 impliying convergence in probability to 1}  
$

Comment: You're fine up to the last statement, which doesn't make any sense -  the $X_n$ are already stationary in distribution, and that distribution is certainly not concentrated at $1$. Perhaps you meant to write the following -  $F_{Y_n}(x) = F_{X_n}^n(x) \to 0$ for $x<1$ and $\forall n, F_{X_n}(x) = 1$ for $x \ge 1$, so $F_{Y_n} \to \mathbf{1}_{[1,\infty)}$, and so $Y_n \overset{d}\to 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Beware that $F_{X_n}(t) = \begin{cases} 0 && t \leq 0 \\
\frac{t+1}{2} && 0 \leq t \leq 1 \\
1 && t \geq 1 \end{cases}$.
So you get $$F_{Y_n}(t)= F_{X_n}(t)^n = \begin{cases} 0 && t \leq 0 \\
\bigg(\frac{t+1}{2}\bigg)^n && 0 \leq t \leq 1 \\
1 && t \geq 1 \end{cases} \quad \to \quad
 F_X(t) = \begin{cases} 0, && t < 1 \\
1, && t \geq 1\end{cases}$$
So, for every $t$ for which $F_X$ is continuous, $F_{Y_n}(t)$ convergences to $F_X(t)$, which is the CDF of a constant r.v. Thus, $Y_n$ truly converges to a constant r.v. (and, as you mentioned, the convergence in probability follows).

Comment: You're right, I'll edit that.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. This made it a lot clearer.

Comment: You're welcome ;)